# Javascript - Run once per session

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the code below to execute only once when the website first loads. 
I tried it with cookies and sessionstorage. But I have never found the right solution. Maybe it was wrong. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve that with session storage? I've never done anything with it. maybe something like this? :

```
 if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
    $('#my_div');
    sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = 1;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```js
var my_div;
topIgnore = 100;  // (in pixel units) used for function ignoreTop

window.onload = function() {
  my_div = document.getElementById('my_div');
  var my_div_style = window.getComputedStyle(my_div);
  var width_div = parseInt(my_div_style.width, 10);  // remove 'px' from string
  var height_div = parseInt(my_div_style.height, 10);
  // make sure the property exists, else you can get a NaN
  my_div.style.left = 0;
  my_div.style.top = 0;
  // event
  window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // my_div.innerHTML = e.pageX +' - '+ (leftBorder + width_div) +' - '+ width_div;
    cursorIsInsideDiv(e);
  }
  // TO DO: feel free to make similar functions for left/right/bottom
  // removes the first 100px
  function ignoreTop(top) {
    if(top < topIgnore) {
      return topIgnore;
    }
    return top;
  }
  function cursorIsInsideDiv(e) {
    var leftBorder = parseInt(my_div.style.left, 10); // remove 'px' from string
    var topBorder  = parseInt(my_div.style.top, 10);  
    // move left 
    if( e.pageX <  leftBorder ) {
      my_div.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    }
    // move right
    else if( e.pageX >  (leftBorder + width_div)) {
      my_div.style.left = (e.pageX - width_div ) + 'px';
    }
    // move up 
    if( e.pageY <  topBorder ) {
      var top = e.pageY ;
      top = ignoreTop(top);
      my_div.style.top = top + 'px';
    }
    // move down
    else if( e.pageY >  (topBorder + height_div)) {
      my_div.style.top = (e.pageY - height_div ) + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#my_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#my_div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div">
  <h2>Newsletter</h2>
  Name: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean once per session, or once "forever"?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see `sessionStorage` in your SO Snippet code.

Comment: it's in the description?

Comment: It should be solved by cookie, what expired at end of session... https://blog.lysender.com/2011/08/setting-session-only-cookie-via-javascript/

Comment: You can find a detailed explanation on how session storage works on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I know, thank you. I already read that

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to set a cookie:

```
document.cookie = "alreadyClicked=1; expires=Fri, 13 Jan 2017 20:00:00 UTC";
```

Then, you can check if it exists by defining a function to find the value (from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp):

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
if (getCookie("alreadyClicked") == "1") {
    // do stuff if already clicked
} else {
    // prompt for click?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just inserted the code between. It worked. Corrected if that is wrong.

```
 if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
$('#my_div');
sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = 1;
```

}